# 301 redirect an URL with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I use this code and it works fine:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /categories/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} channels
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /channels/? [L,R=301]
```

but if I add the following code, the first code doesn't works anymore:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /watch\.php\?tag=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /watch.php?tag=$1 [L]
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work anymore? What happens when you enter a url with a query sting containing `category` or `channels`?

Comment: for category: `categories/index.php?home` and for channels `channels/index.php?home` and I got this error `Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`